# Open source browser with command line option to check for errors retrieving the page?

Tags: browser, command-line-arguments, command-line-tool

I have a couple of TVs powered by Raspberry Pis - they have Raspbian installed and boot straight into Midori's full-screen mode. They display metrics and as such they should always be on and displaying a fixed page.

I recently fixed a problem with the wifi frequently dropping by adding a cron job that does an `ifup` on the wlan interface whenever it detects that the network is down, and that has resolved a lot of the issues with downtime.

However now I'm running into the issue where whenever the page itself is unavailable, the browser is "stuck" at an error page (a frequent one I get is "Connection terminated unexpectedly"). What would be ideal is a browser with a command line option to return the status code of the page it currently has open / whether or not any errors have occurred on the page, and if so, I can reload the page or something similar to bring it back up. I've already checked the [Midori terminal options](https://midori.jottit.com/terminal_options) as well as the [Chromium ones](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but neither of them seem to have what I'm looking for, and googling this has proved difficult. If anyone knows of a browser or a tool that can help me with what I'd be doing, I'd be very grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use wget or curl for this.  Both are command line tools to get web pages and have options to examine the return codes.

For example:

```
webmarc@plato:~$ wget http://www.google.com/  -S  -O /dev/null 2>&1 |  grep HTTP\/
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Here `-S` tells wget to print the server headers, `-O` saves the resultant file to /dev/null because I'm not interested in the contents, just the status code.   The `2>&1` is required because wget prints this all on stderr.  And finally, just piping this to grep for part of the string that is in every response code (HTTP/1.1 is part of every status code these days, but I left the version out so that it will work with v1.2 or 2.0).

You could setup a bash shell script along the lines of

```
$RESULT=`pi@kali:~$ wget http://www.google.com/  -S  -O /dev/null 2>&1 |  grep HTTP\/`

if [[ $RESULT != "  HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]
   then fix_teh_broken.sh
fi
```

Stick something like that in cron on a 1 or 5 minute schedule and you're good to go.

Obviously, substitute the URL you want to monitor for google.